# Mock mail on xampp development box

Tags: php, email, testing, mocking, xampp

I have a local development box that I code on before I transfer my programs to a test server.  It's a basic xampp set up.  However, this limits my ability to test on the local box when I have to send mail in my program.  Is there a way to mock this?  I don't have any desire to set up a mail server on my local machine.  Most questions on this subject on stack deal with setting up a mail server.  That's why I'm asking this particular question.

As always, Thank you for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to just use GMAIL via SMTP (easy enough to setup a free test GMAIL account). ProjectPier has a tutorial on it, just read between the lines and set it up for your needs: http://www.projectpier.org/node/817

There is also a generic tutorial, which I would prefer to use, here: http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/

**EDIT**

The gist, just because you cannot trust external sources to stay alive here is re-write of what they talk about:

First up you will need to edit the php.ini (c:\xampp\php\php.ini). locate the [mail function]  and change the following settings:

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_from = gmailusername@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Make sure that you put in your proper xampp install path and drive letter. Next we need to edit the sendmail.ini,  `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`  add the following, (note you may have to comment out the mercury section):

```
account GmailTest
tls on
tls_certcheck off
host smtp.gmail.com
from gmailusername@gmail.com
auth on
user gmailusername@gmail.com
password gmailpassword
port 465
```

And finally modify the account default and set it to `GmailTest` and you should be good to go. Credits for the above goto http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/

Answer (score 0):

Is it connected to the internet? If you have access to other mail servers (Gmail, Host Provider Email) you can reroute your email using their settings.